Is the batter out Hit wicket if they break the wicket while playing a second shot to defend the stumps?
The batter completed their shot but the ball hit them or their bat and started rolling towards the stumps.
In the process of stopping the ball, the batter hit the stumps with the bat and dislodged a bail or removed a stump from the ground. Is it considered out Hit wicket?

Could you explain any reason you think this would not be out?

Yes it is as its part of completing the shot to the ball.  Law  35.1.1.4 in lawfully making a second or further stroke for the purpose of guarding his/her wicket within the provisions of Law 34.3 (Ball lawfully struck more than once).
